# What does it mean when a "dig" command with "+nssearch" option returns nothing?

Tags: dns, nameservers, dig

When I run the following dig command on www.google.com with the +nssearch option I get no results:

```
mac$ dig www.google.com +nssearch
mac$
```

Can someone explain why no data is returned here? The +nssearch option reads the SOA of all the authoritative name servers I believe.  Does this mean there are no authoritative name servers? How is that possible? The domain www.google.com obviously works so I was expecting some sort of result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.google.com` is not a zone, but a name in a zone. Therefore it doesn't have any NS records (or SOA records) for dig to display. Try dropping the `www.` bit and you'll get more output.

Answer (score 4):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40522
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         20      IN      A       74.125.196.106
www.google.com.         20      IN      A       74.125.196.104
www.google.com.         20      IN      A       74.125.196.99
www.google.com.         20      IN      A       74.125.196.147
www.google.com.         20      IN      A       74.125.196.105
www.google.com.         20      IN      A       74.125.196.103

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.186.1#53(192.168.186.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 17 17:17:37 CDT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 139
```

From "man dig":

> +[no]nssearch
>              When this option is set, dig attempts to find the authoritative name servers for the zone containing the name being
>   looked up and display
>              the SOA record that each name server has for the zone.

Since there's no authority section in the response, +nssearch is going to return nothing.